# Reading data from Dataframe using other Dataframe data as iloc inputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to grab value from an existing df using iloc coordinates stored in another df, then stored that value in the second df.

df_source (source):

```
        Category1   Category2   Category3
Bucket1 100 200 300
Bucket2 400 500 600
Bucket3 700 800 900
```

df_coord (coordinates):

```
Index_X Index_Y 
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

Want:
df_coord

```
Index_X Index_Y Added
0   0   100
1   1   500
2   2   900
```

I'm more familiar with analytical language like SAS, where data is processed one line at a time, so the natural approach for me was this:

```
df_coord['Added'] = df_source.iloc[df_coord[Index_X][df_coord[Index_Y]]
```

When I tried this I got an error, which I understand as df_coord[Index_X] does not refer to the data on the same row. I have seen a few posts where using a "axis=1" option worked for their respective cases, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could index the underlying ndarray, i.e calling the `values` method, using the columns in  `df_coord` as first and second axis:

```
df_coord['Added'] = df_source.values[df_coord.Index_X, df_coord.Index_Y]

     Index_X  Index_Y Added
0        0      0      100
1        1      1      500
2        2      2      900
```

Comment: @YilunZhang you just removed all my text, never do such edits without checking first with whom has answered

Comment: Won't this also just change the columns instead of actually adding something? Just wondering in cause of you need to keeping adding values and retain previously added ones.

Comment: The problem is just about indexing the dataframe @D.Sanders

Comment: there are two different dataframes there though, so if he wants to keep adding to df_coord from df_source, he would have to do something different right? @yatu